# Hive : Parsing pipe delimited data which also has escape characters and other special characters

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to parse and load the below data into Hive external table from a `text` file.

Ex. data:

```
 "100'082 \"|"ABC~01"|"Mana|ger1 \"|"ABC01@m'a`il.com"
```

Using below query:

```
create external table test3
(EmpID STRING, 
EmpName STRING, 
Designation STRING, 
Email STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  ('field.delim'='"|"')
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location '/home/hdp/samplefiles'
tblproperties ('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

The data was loaded into the table as

```
| "100'082 \   | ABC~01         | Mana|ger1 \        | ABC01@m"a`il.com"  |
```

But I want data like this

```
| 100'082 \   | ABC~01         | Mana|ger1 \        | ABC01@m"a`il.com  |
```

Without the double quotes at start of the column1 and in the end of column4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use open OpenCsvSerde in place of MultiDelimitSerDe. Use the below query, it will work as expected in the question.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test3 (EmpID STRING, 
EmpName STRING, 
Designation STRING, 
Email STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('separatorChar' = '|\|"|\||"\|"|"','quoteChar'= '\"','escapeChar'= '\,')
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/home/hdp/samplefiles'
tblproperties ('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

The result of the select query will be :

```
hive> select * from test3;
OK
100'082 \       ABC~01  Mana|ger1 \     ABC01@m'a`il.com
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, I got the result for the example data.. But in my production data some there are some double quotes present in between the data like this "ABC01@m"a`il.com". Is there any solution for this.

Comment: @karthik16 . Looks like the built-in OpenCSVSerde uses opencsv library and it can handle even numers of double quotes. Since in the example you giving above "ABC01@m"a`il.com", there is odd number of double quote i.e there is dangling quote for which there is no ending quote. Thats where the error comes in. These situations are perfectly handled in spark 2 and above, In spark they are using databricks csv library, which can handle all these scenarios. You can create your custom serde using the databricks csv library.

Comment: For information, databricks CSV library internally uses uniVocity csv parsers.Use uniVocity for creating your serde. This is the github url : https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers